# Code First - change membership  database dynamically for an entity 

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-first

I present to you my situation: I have 2 tables, for example, orders lists and customers; to each order is associated with a customer, the orders table belongs to "RomeAgengy" database and the customers table belongs to "Main" database; I've seen that is possibile using the [Table] attribute for  changing the TableName and the TableSchema to a class dynamically, but not for change the Database.

Is it a possible scenario?

Thanks, bye!

Comment: Create 2 different contexts, RomeContext and MainContext.  Map the orders and not customers to the RomeContext using Fluent API.  Map customers and not orders to the MainContext using Fluent API.  Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: No thanks, I found another solution: using Sql Server synonyms.